# Python compare two columns of a list

Tags: python, pandas

How can I compare two columns of a list in python? I already tried this, but it gives the error as described below:

```
import pandas as pd 

TrainDate=pd.read_csv('../input/train_date.csv', delimiter=',', nrows=10, skiprows=0)
TrainDateNumeric=TrainDate.fillna(0).values

if (TrainDateNumeric[:,1] == TrainDateNumeric[:,2] ):
    print ("Yes")
```

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: That's not a list; that's a numpy array.

Comment: And the exception message is easily searched for. Have you tried seeing what it means? Numpy compares the contents *value by value* and produces an array of boolean results, not *one* boolean value. So there is no *one* true or false result here.

Comment: looking at what you're trying to do here you should be doing `if (TrainDateNumeric[:,1] == TrainDateNumeric[:,2] ).all():
    print ("Yes")` the issue here is that `if` expects a scalar value using `==` on dataframe columns produces a `Series` of boolean values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are `numpy` array. You have to compare in this way

```
import numpy as np
if np.allclose(Train[:,1], Train[:,2]):
    print ("Yes")
```